Swift Package Manager Static Library problem
I have added Realm and RealmSwift libraries in my iOS project. My app was fine till 2 days back. Suddenly it started giving following error.
Error:Swift package target 'Realm' is linked as a static library by 'Project' and 'Realm', but cannot be built dynamically because there is a package product with the same name.
I don't find any static libraries in my app. I tried deleting library from Project->Package Dependencies. But XCode is throwing below compiler Error
Missing required modules: 'Realm.Private', 'Realm', 'Realm.Swift'

This is likely due to a recent change. Please review the Install & Setup Guide. If you use Cocoapods, be sure your podfile matches the docs and if using SPM, be sure to note the info the Dynamic Framework Section and be sure you're only adding one package Changed in version 10.49.3: Instead of adding both, only add one package

This is likely due to a recent change in the Realm SDK and install setup.
Please review the Install & Setup Guide.
If you use Cocoapods, be sure your podfile matches the docs and adjust the iOS/macOS version accordingly.
platform :ios, '12.0'  //or for macOS use platform :osx, '13.0'
target 'MyDeviceSDKProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for MyDeviceSDKProject
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10'
end

If using SPM, be sure to note the info the Dynamic Framework Section

To use the Privacy Manifest supplied by the SDK, build RealmSwift as a
dynamic framework.

and be sure you're only adding one package

Changed in version 10.49.3: Instead of adding both, only add one
package.
Select either RealmSwift or Realm, then click Add Package.


For anyone else, as linked to by others, the Install Guide says to link to either Realm or RealmSwift (not too obvious).
In my case, using SPM, I had to link my target to RealmSwift only.
